# Getting unknown attribute error on spec - works fine in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2

I have a spec (Rspec 2.13.1 and rails 3.2.19) and am getting the following error

1) ApiMenusController task0041: test saving new menu will create new menu
     Failure/Error: post :create, {is_new: "true", location_id: lucques.id, name: "my newer jtjt menu"}
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: attributes_changes
     # ./app/models/save_app_event.rb:37:in `before_save'

My AppEvent looks like this:

```
class AppEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :loggable_id, :loggable_type, :user_id, :event, :attributes_changes, :location_id, :menu_id
```

It is called in a before_save

```
class SaveAppEvent
  def self.before_save(model)
    Rails.logger.info("within SaveAppEvent with a " + model.class.to_s)
    tmp=model.changes.except(:admin_frag).except(:menu_item_frag)
    if model.class.to_s=='Menu'
      Rails.logger.info("within SaveAppEvent with menu.location_id #{model.location_id}")
      tmp_menu_id=model.id
      tmp_menu_id=0 if !tmp_menu_id
      tmp_location_id=model.location_id
      event="a menu was saved with location_id: #{tmp_location_id} "
      #Rails.logger.info("within SaveAppEvent with name location_id: #{location_id} and menu_id: #{menu_id}")
    else
      menu_id=nil
      location_id=nil
    end
    Rails.logger.info("within SaveAppEvent right before creation location_id: #{tmp_location_id} and menu_id: #{tmp_menu_id} and attributes_changes: #{tmp}")
    AppEvent.create event: event, menu_id: tmp_menu_id,  attributes_changes: tmp, user_id: model.current_user_id, loggable_type: model.class.name, loggable_id: model.id 
  end
```

The info is there:

```
within SaveAppEvent right before creation location_id: 95 and menu_id: 0 and attributes_changes: {"location_id"=>[nil, 95], "name"=>[nil, "my newer jtjt menu"]}
```

For some reason, in this context, it doesn't think attributes_changes exists. On development, it works fine. Why would test environment see attributes on an object differently?

Comment: Is your test database up to date with migrations?  Did you prepare it before running `rspec` using `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: ugh... I think that might have been it.